# how to detect and modify lower case letters in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a variable named `ID` looks like the following.

```
ID
ABC.L
ABCa.L
BDE.L
BDEna.L
BNE.F
HDF.A
```

The last character or the last two character of this variable before `.` might be in lower case. I want to check if it is the case, if it is the case I will create a new variable and drop the lower case characters. If there is no lower cased character the new variable will be the same as the original variable. Can anyone kindly suggest me how can I achieve this please?

```
ID      New_ID
ABC.L   ABC.L
ABCa.L  ABC.L
BDE.L   BDE.L
BDEna.L BDE.L
BNE.F   BNE.F
HDF.A   HDF.A
```

Comment: [compress](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212246.htm)

Comment: Please include anything you've tried in your questions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COMPRESS function to K=keep U=uppercase alphabetic characters including the .=period

```
254  data have;
255     input ID $;
256     newid = compress(id,'.','KU');
257     put 'NOTE: ' (_all_)(=);
258     cards;

NOTE: ID=ABC.L newid=ABC.L
NOTE: ID=ABCa.L newid=ABC.L
NOTE: ID=BDE.L newid=BDE.L
NOTE: ID=BDEna.L newid=BDE.L
NOTE: ID=BNE.F newid=BNE.F
NOTE: ID=HDF.A newid=HDF.A
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to use prxchange function. Here [a-z] indicates lowercase letters // here means replace it with nothing. -1 indicates as many times it is present.

```
 data want;
 set have;
 new_id1=prxchange('s/[a-z]//',-1, id);
 run;
```